# Synonymize [parse-url] and [url-parsing]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

[url-parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-parsing) is the process of splitting a URL into parts. This tag has 80 questions and no wiki.

[parse_url is the PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), which explains why 47 out of 56 questions which were tagged with [parse-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-url) have the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag as well.

Ironically, this tag has a wiki that does not mention PHP at all and is pretty generic. Furthermore, the excerpt of [parse-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-url) contains the name of the other tag:

> url-parsing is the process of splitting a Universal Resource Locator
>   into its component parts usually to extract parameters made as part of
>   a request or to filter requests.

I believe those tags are essentially the same and it'd be well worth to synonymize them, but I don't have the required score in any of them.

We can only make [parse-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-url) a synonym of [url-parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-parsing) (because 56 * 1.25 is less than 80 - [see the restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92271/260312)).

Comment: Which one should be made a synonym of the other?

Comment: So, [tag:parse-url] refers to `parse_url`, but [tag:url-parsing] is a bit more generic, and can be used for URL parsing in general.