# Conflict of parse-url, url-parsing, and urlParse tags

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request, synonym-request

Today I was asking a question about url parameters and how to parse it. I noticed that we have three similar tags [url-parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-parsing) (91 questions), [urlparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlparse) (88 questions), and [parse-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-url) (66 questions). I think they have same meaning and we should merge them.

[This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296251/3328979) mentions that [parse-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-url) is also a PHP function

> Ironically, this tag has a wiki that does not mention PHP at all and
>   is pretty generic

Obviously we cannot create a tag for each function. I suggest that we keep [url-parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-parsing) and remove other twos. I think it works with this term:

> If a tag has more than 50 questions in it, the proposed synonym tag
>   cannot have a question count greater than 1.25x the master tag

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).